# Resolve dependency between two installers in Zenject

Tags: unity, c#, dependency-injection

Im trying to implemet dependency injection in my Unity project by using Zenject. I have two installers. The first one is Monoinstaller who is responsible for injection and creation of scene objects, such as transform parents in which objects will spawn:

```
        public class SceneInstaller : MonoInstaller
    {
        [SerializeField] private Transform _safeArea;
        [SerializeField] private Transform _mangersParent;
        public override void InstallBindings()
        {
        print("scene");
        Container.Bind<Transform>().FromInstance(_safeArea).AsCached().WithConcreteId("SafeArea").NonLazy();
        Container.Bind<Transform>().FromInstance(_mangersParent).AsCached().WithConcreteId("Managers Parent").NonLazy();
        Container.Bind<Transform>().FromNewComponentOnNewGameObject().AsCached().WithConcreteId("Field Parent").NonLazy();
        Container.Bind<Transform>().FromNewComponentOnNewGameObject().AsCached().WithConcreteId("Apple Parent").NonLazy();
    }
}
```

And the second one is ScriptableObjectInstaller that creates and injects the game field and object manager

```
   public class FieldManagerInstaller : ScriptableObjectInstaller
{
    [SerializeField] private ExpandFieldData _expandField;
    [Inject(Id = "Safe Area")] private RectTransform _safeArea;
    [SerializeField] private FieldManager _fieldManager;
    [Inject(Id = "Managers Parent")] private Transform _fieldManagerParent;
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Debug.Log("field");
        var expandField = Container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<ExpandFieldData>(_expandField, _safeArea);
        Container.Bind<ExpandFieldData>().FromInstance(expandField).AsSingle();
        var fieldManager = Container.InstantiatePrefabForComponent<FieldManager>(_fieldManager, _fieldManagerParent);
        Container.Bind<FieldManager>().FromInstance(fieldManager).AsSingle();
    }
}
```

The problem is that SOinstaller uses some variables from Monoinstaller e.g. _fieldManagersParent which is parent for every manager on scene. But as far as i understood SOInstallers initialize earlier then Monoinstallers. And when FieldManagerInstaller already started to install his bindings SceneInstaller still not working and Zenject resolver throws an exception:

```
ZenjectException: Unable to resolve 'RectTransform (ID: Safe Area)' while building object with type 'FieldManagerInstaller'. Object graph:
FieldManagerInstaller
ZenjectException: Unable to resolve 'Transform (ID: Field Parent)' while building object with type 'FieldManager'. Object graph:
FieldManage
```

[image]

Logs also confirm this. Does anybody knows how to execute installers in specified order? By the way is it good practice to create a new gameobject and inject it by using `FromNewComponentOnNewGameObject` or there is another better ways?